# Transform a dataframe into a tree structure list of lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tree, networkd3

I have a data.frame with two columns representing a hierarchical tree, with parents and nodes.

I want to transform its structure in a way that I can use as an input for the function `d3tree`, from `d3Network` package.

Here's my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c("Canada","Canada","Quebec","Quebec","Ontario","Ontario"),c("Quebec","Ontario","Montreal","Quebec City","Toronto","Ottawa"))
names(df) <- c("parent","child")
```

And I want to transform it to this structure

```
Canada_tree <- list(name = "Canada", children = list(
                                                list(name = "Quebec", 
                children = list(list(name = "Montreal"),list(name = "Quebec City"))),
                                                 list(name = "Ontario", 
                children = list(list(name = "Toronto"),list(name = "Ottawa")))))
```

I have succesfully transformed this particular case using this code below:

```
fill_list <- function(df,node) node <- as.character(node)if (is.leaf(df,node)==TRUE){
    return (list(name = node))
  }
  else {
    new_node = df[df[,1] == node,2]

    return (list(name = node, children =  list(fill_list(df,new_node[1]),fill_list(df,new_node[2]))))
  }
```

The problem is, it only works with trees which every parent node has exactly two children.
You can see I hard coded the two children (new_node[1] and new_node[2]) as inputs for my recursive function.

I'm trying to figure out a way that I could call the recursive function as many time as the parent's node children. 
Example:

```
fill_list(df,new_node[1]),...,fill_list(df,new_node[length(new_node)])
```

I tried these 3 possibilities but none of it worked:

**First:** Creating a string with all the functions and parameters and then evaluating. It return this error `could not find function fill_functional(df,new_node[1])`. That's because my function wasn´t created by the time I called it after all.

```
fill_functional <- function(df,node) {
  node <- as.character(node)
  if (is.leaf(df,node)==TRUE){
    return (list(name = node))
  }
  else {
    new_node = df[df[,1] == node,2]
    level <- length(new_node)
    xxx <- paste0("(df,new_node[",seq(level),"])")
    lapply(xxx,function(x) eval(call(paste("fill_functional",x,sep=""))))

  }
}
```

**Second:** Using a for loop. But I only got the children of my root node.

```
L <- list()
fill_list <- function(df,node) {
  node <- as.character(node)
  if (is.leaf(df,node)==TRUE){
    return (list(name = node))
  }
  else {
    new_node = df[df[,1] == node,2]

    for (i in 1:length(new_node)){
      L[i] <- (fill_list(df,new_node[i]))
    }

    return (list(name = node, children = L))
  }
}
```

**Third:** Creating a function that populates a list with elements that are functions, and just changing the arguments. But I wasn't able to accomplish anything interesting, and I'm afraid I'll have the same problem as I did on my first try described above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a recursive definition:

```
maketreelist <- function(df, root = df[1, 1]) {
  if(is.factor(root)) root <- as.character(root)
  r <- list(name = root)
  children = df[df[, 1] == root, 2]
  if(is.factor(children)) children <- as.character(children)
  if(length(children) > 0) {
    r$children <- lapply(children, maketreelist, df = df)
    }
  r
  }

canadalist <- maketreelist(df)
```

That produces what you desire. This function assumes that the first column of the `data.frame` (or `matrix`) you pass in contains the `parent` column and the second column has the `child`. it also takes a `root` parameter which allows you to specify a starting points. It will default to the first parent in the list.

But if you really are interested in playing round with trees. The `igraph` package might be of interest

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g)
```

[image: canada tree in igraph]

Comment: In case interested, please see this [new similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157332).

Comment: What if I am trying to avoid having extra `children` nodes in my tree?

Comment: Solved my own question, with the *purr* package I changed the function to return `flatten(r)`.