# Convert a data frame to a treeNetwork compatible list

Tags: r, networkd3

Consider the following data frame:

```
   Country     Provinces          City Zone
1   Canada   Newfondland      St Johns    A
2   Canada           PEI Charlottetown    B
3   Canada   Nova Scotia       Halifax    C
4   Canada New Brunswick   Fredericton    D
5   Canada        Quebec            NA   NA
6   Canada        Quebec   Quebec City   NA
7   Canada       Ontario       Toronto    A
8   Canada       Ontario        Ottawa    B
9   Canada      Manitoba      Winnipeg    C
10  Canada  Saskatchewan        Regina    D
```

Would there be a clever way to convert it to a `treeNetwork` compatible list (from the `networkD3` package) in the form of:

```
CanadaPC <- list(name = "Canada",
                 children = list(
                   list(name = "Newfoundland",
                        children = list(list(name = "St. John's",
                                             children = list(list(name = "A"))))),
                   list(name = "PEI",
                        children = list(list(name = "Charlottetown",
                                             children = list(list(name = "B"))))),
                   list(name = "Nova Scotia",
                        children = list(list(name = "Halifax",
                                             children = list(list(name = "C"))))),
                   list(name = "New Brunswick",
                        children = list(list(name = "Fredericton",
                                             children = list(list(name = "D"))))),
                   list(name = "Quebec",
                        children = list(list(name = "Quebec City"))),
                   list(name = "Ontario",
                        children = list(list(name = "Toronto",
                                             children = list(list(name = "A"))),
                                        list(name = "Ottawa",
                                             children = list(list(name = "B"))))),
                   list(name = "Manitoba",
                        children = list(list(name = "Winnipeg",
                                             children = list(list(name = "C"))))),
                   list(name = "Saskatchewan",
                        children = list(list(name = "Regina",
                                             children = list(list(name = "D")))))))
```

In order to plot a *Reingold-Tilford* tree that would have an arbitrary set of levels:

[image]

I have tried several sub-optimal routines including a messy combination of `for` loops but I can't get this in the desired format.

Ideally, the function would scale in order to consider the first column as the `root` (starting point) and the other columns would be different levels of children.

---

**Edit**

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839142/transforming-a-data-frame-into-a-tree-structure-list-of-lists-in-r) was asked on the same topic and @MrFlick provided an interesting recursive function. The original data frame had a fixed set of levels. I introduced `NA`s to add another level of complexity (arbitrary set of levels) that is not adressed in @MrFlick initial solution.

---

**Data**

```
structure(list(Country = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
    Provinces = c("Newfondland", "PEI", "Nova Scotia", "New Brunswick", 
    "Quebec", "Quebec", "Ontario", "Ontario", "Manitoba", "Saskatchewan"
    ), City = c("St Johns", "Charlottetown", "Halifax", "Fredericton", 
    NA, "Quebec City", "Toronto", "Ottawa", "Winnipeg", "Regina"
    ), Zone = c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA, NA, "A", "B", "C", 
    "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("Country", 
"Provinces", "City", "Zone"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better strategy for this scenario may be a recursive `split()` Here's such an implementation. First, here's the sample data

```
dd<-structure(list(Country = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
    Provinces = c("Newfondland", "PEI", "Nova Scotia", "New Brunswick", 
    "Quebec", "Quebec", "Ontario", "Ontario", "Manitoba", "Saskatchewan"
    ), City = c("St Johns", "Charlottetown", "Halifax", "Fredericton", 
    NA, "Quebec City", "Toronto", "Ottawa", "Winnipeg", "Regina"
    ), Zone = c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA, NA, "A", "B", "C", 
    "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("Country", 
"Provinces", "City", "Zone"))
```

note that' i've replaced the `"NA"` strings with true `NA` values. Now, the function

```
rsplit <- function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x[,1]),,drop=FALSE]
    if(nrow(x)==0) return(NULL)
    if(ncol(x)==1) return(lapply(x[,1], function(v) list(name=v)))
    s <- split(x[,-1, drop=FALSE], x[,1])
    unname(mapply(function(v,n) {if(!is.null(v)) list(name=n, children=v) else list(name=n)}, lapply(s, rsplit), names(s), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
}
```

Then we can run

```
rsplit(dd)
```

It seems to work with the test data. The only difference is the order in which the children nodes are arranged.

Comment: I think it does not provide the proper nesting as the `treeNetwork()` function does not render the expected output. I edited the question to reflect the proper `dput()` structure

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the input? You don't include any code to test the result.

Comment: Actually this solution doesn't assume one root node so it returns a list. Try `rsplit(dd)[[1]]`